# Is it true that union of an increasing chain of well-ordered sets is well-ordered?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

•Is it true that union of an increasing chain of well-ordered sets is well-ordered?

Can you say that what is 'increasing chain of well-ordered set' mean? Can you help? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $m \in \Bbb{Z}$, the set $Z_{>m} = \{i : \Bbb{Z} \mid i > m\}$ is well-ordered under the usual ordering of the integers, i.e., there is no infinitely descending sequence $x_1 > x_2 > x_3 > \ldots$ of elements of $Z_{>m}$. The sequence of sets $Z_{>-1}, Z_{>-2}, Z_{>-3}, \ldots$ is an ascending chain of sets, i.e., we have $Z_{>-1} \subseteq Z_{>-2} \subseteq Z_{>-3} \subseteq \ldots$. What is the union of the  sets $Z_{>-i}$? Is it well-ordered?

Comment: I think yes it is well-ordered because: let $,A\subseteq Z_{-1}\subseteq Z_{-2} ..$ Then $A$ does have a minimal element:zero, right?

Comment: No: think about the **union** of the $Z_{>-i}$, i.e., the set of all integers that are members of at least one of the $Z_{>-i}$.

Comment: Ahh.. Yes. It is no well ordered. It does no have minimal element.

Comment: Part of the question asks for a definition of "increasing chain". Your answer is based on the tacit assumption that the ordering of well-ordered sets is "$\langle A_1,\le_1\rangle\le\langle A_2,\le_2\rangle$ iff $\langle A_1,\le_1\rangle$ is a substructure of $\langle A_2,\le_2\rangle$." You get a different answer if you replace "substructure" with "initial segment".

Comment: In my experience, "chain of sets" with no other qualification **always** means chain with respect to inclusion. My hint includes, in the bits beginning "i.e." an indication of what the definitions the OP was uncertain about mean. I.e., I was explaining the definitions (and the standard "tacit" assumption) by example. That's why I called my answer a hint. As the answer got a tick, I presume the OP got what they needed out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the set of negative integers isn't well ordered but can be written as the union of well ordered sets.

Comment: I like this, because it points out that there is probably a missing hypothesis in the question.

Comment: @Lubin: the question has a definite answer as it stands. Jonathan's answer (like mine) hints at what that answer is.